# ASP.NET and C#: create button that sends keyword to website with search bar

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button, code-behind, searchbar

I am new to ASP.NET and C#. In a Web App, I know I can create a button that opens a webpage:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Launch browser
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.nhl.com/jets");
}
```

But if the landing page has a search bar, how can I send a keyword to that search bar upon clicking the button? For clarity, say that my code-behind declares that keyword like this:
`string keyword = Keyword.Text`. How can I make sure that this keyword is automatically sent to the search bar, so that users can see the results without having to type the keyword?

Comment: obviously it depends if opening page support such action

Comment: @Selvin let's assume that it does

Comment: then you have to ask the author ...fx for google it's `q` parameter in query string ... but **obviously may be different for different sites**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you should use **webBrowser** automation. i adapted this methods i wrote before to your website, just add your little adjustments:

```
... string keyboard = Keyword.Text

    public String GetKeyboardValueForSearch() {
        return keyboard;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new 
        WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
        webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.nhl.com/jets");            
    }

    void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlElement search = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("top-nav__search- 
        autocomplete__input");
        if(search != null)
        {
            search.SetAttribute("value", GetKeyboardValueForSearch());
            foreach(HtmlElement ele in search.Parent.Children)
            {
                if (ele.TagName.ToLower() == "input" && ele.Name.ToLower() == "go")
                {
                    ele.InvokeMember("click");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```